# Jackson API: partially update a string

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I have a very complex Json object that I get as a String:

```
{ "a": ..., "b":..., /* lots of other properties */ "z":... }
```

that I read partially with Jackson and map into a Java class:

```
class PartialObjectForB { @JsonProperty("b") private ObjectB b; }
```

I use the readValue() method from the ObjectMapper class and get what I want... So far, so good.

Now, I want to update some values in PartialObjectForB and update the initial string I had.
I figured how to update a Java object with jackson (by using readerForUpdating) but can't find how to do the opposite: update a Json object/string with a Java object.

I know how to solve quickly that problem by using JSONObject. For example, if I just want to update 1 value:

```
JSONObject j = new JSONObject(/* the full json string */);
j.getJSONObject("b").getJSONObject("bb")/* etc. */.put("bbbb", 4);
j.toString(); // will give me the full original text with only "b" updated.
```

But can't find how to do it with jackson.

Any idea?

Notes:

- My input/output are strings, can't change that.
- I don't know what data is in the json object. I just know that I may have the property "b" and that if I don't I can create it.
- I may want to deserialize and update more than 1 property at the root level (e.g: "b", "h" and "w").
- This problem is not recursive. Meaning: I have a full representation of the values I unserialize (no unknown properties).
- The json object, as a string, is made of a few thousand bytes, but the piece(s) I want to update is usually a lot smaller (e.g: around 100 bytes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full executable source with benchmark included is:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Random;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;
import org.codehaus.jackson.Version;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonSerializer;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.Module;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializerProvider;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.BasicBeanDescription;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase;
import org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JacksonModule {

    private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
    private static final int COUNT = 0;
    private static final int REPEAT_HEADER = 40;

    static {
        MAPPER.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        MAPPER.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_NULL_PROPERTIES, false);
        MAPPER.registerModule(new MyModule());
    }
    private DataProcessor sdp;
    private long[] sum = new long[5];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
        new JacksonModule().start();
    }

    public JacksonModule() throws IOException, JSONException {
        this.sdp = new DataProcessor();
    }

    public void start() throws IOException, JSONException {
        run(-1, false); // load classes: slow
        if (COUNT > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i) {
                if (i % REPEAT_HEADER == 0) {
                    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    print("", "RO JSONObject", "RO Jackson", "R/- Jackson", "R/W JSONObject", "R/W Jackson");
                    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                }
                run(i, true);
            }
            System.out.println("-- AVERAGE ----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            print(1, sum[0] / COUNT, sum[1] / COUNT, sum[2] / COUNT, sum[3] / COUNT, sum[4] / COUNT);
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            print("", "RO JSONObject", "RO Jackson", "R/- Jackson", "R/W JSONObject", "R/W Jackson");
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        }
    }

    public void run(int i, boolean print) throws JSONException, IOException {
        long t1 = sdp.doReadWithJSONObject();
        long t2 = sdp.doReadWithJackson();
        long t3 = sdp.doReadForUpdatingWithJacksonButDontWrite();
        long t4 = sdp.doSomeWritingWithJSONObject();
        long t5 = sdp.doSomeWritingWithJackson();
        if (print) {
            print(i, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5);
            sum[0] += t1;
            sum[1] += t2;
            sum[2] += t3;
            sum[3] += t4;
            sum[4] += t5;
        }
    }

    private void print(int index, long t1, long t2, long t3, long t4, long t5) {
        print(Integer.toString(index), String.format("%,d", t1), String.format("%,d", t2), String.format("%,d", t3), String.format("%,d", t4), String.format("%,d", t5));
    }

    private void print(String i0, String a, String b, String c, String d, String e) {
        System.out.println("|"
                + StringUtils.leftPad(i0, 5) + "|"
                + StringUtils.leftPad(a, 15) + "|"
                + StringUtils.leftPad(b, 15) + "|"
                + StringUtils.leftPad(c, 15) + "|"
                + StringUtils.leftPad(d, 15) + "|"
                + StringUtils.leftPad(e, 15) + "|");
    }

    private static class DataProcessor {

        private DataStore store;
        private long t0, t1;

        private DataProcessor() throws IOException, JSONException {
            this.store = new DataStore(customer, browser);
        }

        public long doReadWithJSONObject() throws JSONException {
            t0 = System.nanoTime();
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(store.readData(null)); // can throw JSONException
            JSONObject customer = json.getJSONObject("customer");  // can throw JSONException
            JSONObject browserInfo = json.getJSONObject("browser");  // can throw JSONException
            // need to do manually the mapping and figure out what is exactly in this object. Hell no!
            t1 = System.nanoTime();
            return t1 - t0;
        }

        public long doReadWithJackson() throws IOException {
            t0 = System.nanoTime();
            KnownPart obj = store.readData(null, KnownPart.class);
            t1 = System.nanoTime();
            return t1 - t0;
        }

        public long doReadForUpdatingWithJacksonButDontWrite() throws IOException {
            t0 = System.nanoTime();
            KnownPart obj = store.readDataForUpdating(null, KnownPart.class);
            t1 = System.nanoTime();
            return t1 - t0;
        }

        public long doSomeWritingWithJSONObject() throws JSONException {
            t0 = System.nanoTime();
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(store.readData(null)); // can throw JSONException
            JSONObject customer = json.getJSONObject("customer");  // can throw JSONException
            JSONObject browserInfo = json.getJSONObject("browser");  // can throw JSONException
            customer.put("name", "Jackson Doe");
            browserInfo.put("version", "10");
            store.saveData(json);
            t1 = System.nanoTime();
            return t1 - t0;
        }

        public long doSomeWritingWithJackson() throws IOException {
            t0 = System.nanoTime();
            KnownPart obj = store.readDataForUpdating(null, KnownPart.class);
            obj.customer.name = "Jackson Doe";
            obj.browser.version = "10";
            store.saveData(obj);
            t1 = System.nanoTime();
            return t1 - t0;
        }
    }

    private static class DataStore {

        private final String data;

        private DataStore(Customer customer, BrowserInfo browser) throws IOException, JSONException {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(1000);
            try (JsonGenerator jgen = MAPPER.getJsonFactory().createJsonGenerator(sw)) {
                jgen.writeStartObject();
                writeBunchOfProperties(jgen);
                jgen.writeFieldName("customer");
                jgen.writeRawValue(MAPPER.writeValueAsString(customer));
                writeBunchOfProperties(jgen);
                jgen.writeFieldName("browser");
                jgen.writeRawValue(MAPPER.writeValueAsString(browser));
                writeBunchOfProperties(jgen);
                jgen.writeEndObject();
            }
            this.data = sw.toString();
        }

        private void writeBunchOfProperties(JsonGenerator jgen) throws IOException {
            int c = new Random().nextInt(3) + 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < c; ++i) {
                jgen.writeFieldName(RandomStringUtils.random(10));
                jgen.writeRawValue(JSON_LONG);
            }
        }

        public String readData(String query) {
            return data;
        }

        private void saveData(String json) {
            // TODO
        }

        public void saveData(JSONObject json) {
            saveData(json.toString());
        }

        public void saveData(Object obj) throws IOException {
            saveData(MAPPER.writeValueAsString(obj));
        }

        public <T> T readData(String query, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
            return MAPPER.readValue(readData(query), clazz);
        }

        public <T extends UnknownPart> T readDataForUpdating(String query, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
            ObjectNode root = (ObjectNode) MAPPER.readTree(readData(query));
            T obj = MAPPER.readValue(root, clazz);
            obj.tree = root;
            return obj;
        }
    }

    private static abstract class UnknownPart {

         ObjectNode tree;
    }

    private static class KnownPart extends UnknownPart {

        @JsonProperty
        private Customer customer;
        @JsonProperty
        private BrowserInfo browser;
    }

    private static class Customer {

        @JsonProperty
        private int id;
        @JsonProperty
        private String name;
        @JsonProperty
        private Address[] addresses; // just to make it more complex for this example

        public Customer(int id, String name, Address[] addresses) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.addresses = addresses;
        }

        public Customer() {
        }
    }

    private static class Address {

        @JsonProperty
        private String street;
        @JsonProperty
        private String city;

        public Address(String street, String city) {
            this.street = street;
            this.city = city;
        }

        public Address() {
        }
    }

    private static class BrowserInfo {

        @JsonProperty
        private String agent;
        @JsonProperty
        private String version;

        public BrowserInfo(String agent, String version) {
            this.agent = agent;
            this.version = version;
        }

        public BrowserInfo() {
        }
    }

    private static class MyModule extends Module {

        @Override
        public String getModuleName() {
            return "MyModule";
        }

        @Override
        public Version version() {
            return new Version(0, 0, 1, "SNAPSHOT");
        }

        @Override
        public void setupModule(Module.SetupContext context) {
            context.addBeanSerializerModifier(new org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerModifier() {
                private UnknownPartSerializer cs;

                @Override
                public JsonSerializer modifySerializer(SerializationConfig config, BasicBeanDescription beanDesc, JsonSerializer<?> serializer) {
                    return UnknownPart.class.isAssignableFrom(beanDesc.getBeanClass())
                       ? new UnknownPartSerializer((BeanSerializerBase) serializer)
                       : serializer;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private static class UnknownPartSerializer extends BeanSerializerBase {

        public UnknownPartSerializer(BeanSerializerBase src) {
            super(src);
        }

        @Override
        public void serialize(Object bean, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {
            UnknownPart up = (UnknownPart) bean;
            jgen.writeStartObject();
            serializeFields(up, jgen, provider);
            jgen.writeEndObject();
        }

        protected void serializeFields(UnknownPart bean, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {
            final BeanPropertyWriter[] props;
            if (_filteredProps != null && provider.getSerializationView() != null) {
                props = _filteredProps;
            } else {
                props = _props;
            }
            int i = 0;
            try {
                for (final int len = props.length; i < len; ++i) {
                    BeanPropertyWriter prop = props[i];
                    if (prop != null) { // can have nulls in filtered list
                        prop.serializeAsField(bean, jgen, provider);
                        bean.tree.remove(prop.getName());
                    }
                }
                if (_anyGetterWriter != null) {
                    _anyGetterWriter.getAndSerialize(bean, jgen, provider);
                }
                Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> it = bean.tree.getFields();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    Entry<String, JsonNode> e = it.next();
                    jgen.writeFieldName(e.getKey());
                    jgen.writeObject(e.getValue());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                String name = (i == props.length) ? "[anySetter]"
                        : props[i].getName();
                wrapAndThrow(provider, e, bean, name);
            } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
                /* 04-Sep-2009, tatu: Dealing with this is tricky, since we do not
                 *   have many stack frames to spare... just one or two; can't
                 *   make many calls.
                 */
                JsonMappingException mapE = new JsonMappingException("Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)", e);
                String name = (i == props.length) ? "[anySetter]"
                        : props[i].getName();
                mapE.prependPath(new JsonMappingException.Reference(bean, name));
                throw mapE;
            }
        }
    }
    private static Customer customer = new Customer(1, "John Doe", new Address[]{
        new Address("broadway av", "new york"),
        new Address("peachtree st", "atlanta")
    });
    private static BrowserInfo browser = new BrowserInfo("IE", "6.0");
    // some json found on the internet
    private static final String JSON_LONG = "{\"web-app\": {"
            + "\"servlet\": ["
            + "{"
            + "\"servlet-name\": \"cofaxCDS\","
            + "\"servlet-class\": \"org.cofax.cds.CDSServlet\","
            + "\"init-param\": {"
            + "\"configGlossary:installationAt\": \"Philadelphia, PA\","
            + "\"configGlossary:adminEmail\": \"ksm@pobox.com\","
            + "\"configGlossary:poweredBy\": \"Cofax\","
            + "\"configGlossary:poweredByIcon\": \"/images/cofax.gif\","
            + "\"configGlossary:staticPath\": \"/content/static\","
            + "\"templateProcessorClass\": \"org.cofax.WysiwygTemplate\","
            + "\"templateLoaderClass\": \"org.cofax.FilesTemplateLoader\","
            + "\"templatePath\": \"templates\","
            + "\"templateOverridePath\": \"\","
            + "\"defaultListTemplate\": \"listTemplate.htm\","
            + "\"defaultFileTemplate\": \"articleTemplate.htm\","
            + "\"useJSP\": false,"
            + "\"jspListTemplate\": \"listTemplate.jsp\","
            + "\"jspFileTemplate\": \"articleTemplate.jsp\","
            + "\"cachePackageTagsTrack\": 200,"
            + "\"cachePackageTagsStore\": 200,"
            + "\"cachePackageTagsRefresh\": 60,"
            + "\"cacheTemplatesTrack\": 100,"
            + "\"cacheTemplatesStore\": 50,"
            + "\"cacheTemplatesRefresh\": 15,"
            + "\"cachePagesTrack\": 200,"
            + "\"cachePagesStore\": 100,"
            + "\"cachePagesRefresh\": 10,"
            + "\"cachePagesDirtyRead\": 10,"
            + "\"searchEngineListTemplate\": \"forSearchEnginesList.htm\","
            + "\"searchEngineFileTemplate\": \"forSearchEngines.htm\","
            + "\"searchEngineRobotsDb\": \"WEB-INF/robots.db\","
            + "\"useDataStore\": true,"
            + "\"dataStoreClass\": \"org.cofax.SqlDataStore\","
            + "\"redirectionClass\": \"org.cofax.SqlRedirection\","
            + "\"dataStoreName\": \"cofax\","
            + "\"dataStoreDriver\": \"com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver\","
            + "\"dataStoreUrl\": \"jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://LOCALHOST:1433;DatabaseName=goon\","
            + "\"dataStoreUser\": \"sa\","
            + "\"dataStorePassword\": \"dataStoreTestQuery\","
            + "\"dataStoreTestQuery\": \"SET NOCOUNT ON;select test='test';\","
            + "\"dataStoreLogFile\": \"/usr/local/tomcat/logs/datastore.log\","
            + "\"dataStoreInitConns\": 10,"
            + "\"dataStoreMaxConns\": 100,"
            + "\"dataStoreConnUsageLimit\": 100,"
            + "\"dataStoreLogLevel\": \"debug\","
            + "\"maxUrlLength\": 500}},"
            + "{"
            + "\"servlet-name\": \"cofaxEmail\","
            + "\"servlet-class\": \"org.cofax.cds.EmailServlet\","
            + "\"init-param\": {"
            + "\"mailHost\": \"mail1\","
            + "\"mailHostOverride\": \"mail2\"}},"
            + "{"
            + "\"servlet-name\": \"cofaxAdmin\","
            + "\"servlet-class\": \"org.cofax.cds.AdminServlet\"},"
            + ""
            + "{"
            + "\"servlet-name\": \"fileServlet\","
            + "\"servlet-class\": \"org.cofax.cds.FileServlet\"},"
            + "{"
            + "\"servlet-name\": \"cofaxTools\","
            + "\"servlet-class\": \"org.cofax.cms.CofaxToolsServlet\","
            + "\"init-param\": {"
            + "\"templatePath\": \"toolstemplates/\","
            + "\"log\": 1,"
            + "\"logLocation\": \"/usr/local/tomcat/logs/CofaxTools.log\","
            + "\"logMaxSize\": \"\","
            + "\"dataLog\": 1,"
            + "\"dataLogLocation\": \"/usr/local/tomcat/logs/dataLog.log\","
            + "\"dataLogMaxSize\": \"\","
            + "\"removePageCache\": \"/content/admin/remove?cache=pages&id=\","
            + "\"removeTemplateCache\": \"/content/admin/remove?cache=templates&id=\","
            + "\"fileTransferFolder\": \"/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/content/fileTransferFolder\","
            + "\"lookInContext\": 1,"
            + "\"adminGroupID\": 4,"
            + "\"betaServer\": true}}],"
            + "\"servlet-mapping\": {"
            + "\"cofaxCDS\": \"/\","
            + "\"cofaxEmail\": \"/cofaxutil/aemail/*\","
            + "\"cofaxAdmin\": \"/admin/*\","
            + "\"fileServlet\": \"/static/*\","
            + "\"cofaxTools\": \"/tools/*\"},"
            + ""
            + "\"taglib\": {"
            + "\"taglib-uri\": \"cofax.tld\","
            + "\"taglib-location\": \"/WEB-INF/tlds/cofax.tld\"}}}";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Victory! :) I have now an implementation for it and it is not quite simple.
Benchmark Jackson vs JSONObject included.

**Problem** and solution described piece by piece:

First, I have a big json string in a data store that I want to partially deserialize and update. The deserialization has to be partial, but serialization full, so I don't lose the data I didn't deserialize.
Here are the object I am using for the example:

```
   private static class KnownPart {

        @JsonProperty
        private Customer customer;
        @JsonProperty
        private BrowserInfo browser;
    }

    private static class Customer {

        @JsonProperty
        private int id;
        @JsonProperty
        private String name;
        @JsonProperty
        private Address[] addresses; // just to make it more complex for this example

        public Customer(int id, String name, Address[] addresses) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.addresses = addresses;
        }

        public Customer() {
        }
    }

    private static class Address {

        @JsonProperty
        private String street;
        @JsonProperty
        private String city;

        public Address(String street, String city) {
            this.street = street;
            this.city = city;
        }

        public Address() {
        }
    }

    private static class BrowserInfo {

        @JsonProperty
        private String agent;
        @JsonProperty
        private String version;

        public BrowserInfo(String agent, String version) {
            this.agent = agent;
            this.version = version;
        }

        public BrowserInfo() {
        }
    }
```

KnownPart object contains a lot more than 2 properties, but I have no idea which ones exactly and I can not guarantee to keep track of which properties are added to the json string...

I have a data store which has its data encoded in Json. The current implementation uses JSONObject to read/write and supports jackson to read json and map it to "real" Java object (POJOs and more complex objects).
While writing full Json strings with jackson is not a problem, updating an existing string with a Java object that only represents a small part of it is much harder.

Data store problem:

```
    private static class DataStore {

        private final String data;

        private DataStore(Customer customer, BrowserInfo browser) throws IOException, JSONException {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(1000);
            try (JsonGenerator jgen = MAPPER.getJsonFactory().createJsonGenerator(sw)) {
                jgen.writeStartObject();
                writeBunchOfProperties(jgen);
                jgen.writeFieldName("customer");
                jgen.writeRawValue(MAPPER.writeValueAsString(customer));
                writeBunchOfProperties(jgen);
                jgen.writeFieldName("browser");
                jgen.writeRawValue(MAPPER.writeValueAsString(browser));
                writeBunchOfProperties(jgen);
                jgen.writeEndObject();
            }
            this.data = sw.toString();
        }

        private void writeBunchOfProperties(JsonGenerator jgen) throws IOException {
            int c = new Random().nextInt(3) + 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < c; ++i) {
                jgen.writeFieldName(RandomStringUtils.random(10));
                jgen.writeRawValue(JSON_LONG);
            }
        }

        public String readData(String query) {
            return data;
        }

        private void saveData(String json) {
            // Not implemented
        }

        public void saveData(JSONObject json) {
            saveData(json.toString());
        }

        public void saveData(Object obj) throws IOException {
            // problem: ?
        }

        public <T> T readData(String query, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
            return MAPPER.readValue(readData(query), clazz);
        }

        public <T> T readDataForUpdating(String query, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
            // problem: ?
        }
```

At the higher level, I want to be able to do something like:

```
        public long doSomeWritingWithJackson() throws IOException {
            t0 = System.nanoTime();
            KnownPart obj = store.readDataForUpdating(null, KnownPart.class);
            obj.customer.name = "Jackson Doe";
            obj.browser.version = "10";
            store.saveData(obj);
            t1 = System.nanoTime();
            return t1 - t0;
        }
```

without losing the data I didn't read when I save.
Obviously, I don't want to read a 2nd time the data because I'm reading this from a remote host and I don't want to cache it in some static/instance map because I need this to be still very effective in a highly concurrent environment.

So the **solution**, in a few words is:
 - to read the tree of the json string first and use it to deserialize the Json object into the Java object.
 - store the deserialize object (in KnowPart class) and store the tree in some parent abstract class
 - write a Jackson module to customize how bean are serialized. The code is pretty much the same than the original one with the difference that when an attribute from the KnownPart is written, it's key is removed the tree which is in the UnknownPart object, then it is easy to write the unknown part...

The main object becomes:

```
    private static abstract class UnknownPart {

         ObjectNode tree;
    }

    private static class KnownPart extends UnknownPart {

        @JsonProperty
        private Customer customer;
        @JsonProperty
        private BrowserInfo browser;
    }
```

The module only deals with UnknownPart objects:
        private static class MyModule extends Module {

```
        @Override
        public String getModuleName() {
            return "MyModule";
        }

        @Override
        public Version version() {
            return new Version(0, 0, 1, "SNAPSHOT");
        }

        @Override
        public void setupModule(Module.SetupContext context) {
            context.addBeanSerializerModifier(new org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializerModifier() {
                private UnknownPartSerializer cs;

                @Override
                public JsonSerializer modifySerializer(SerializationConfig config, BasicBeanDescription beanDesc, JsonSerializer<?> serializer) {
                   return UnknownPart.class.isAssignableFrom(beanDesc.getBeanClass())
                       ? new UnknownPartSerializer((BeanSerializerBase) serializer)
                       : serializer;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

And the serializer is:

```
    private static class UnknownPartSerializer extends BeanSerializerBase {

        public UnknownPartSerializer(BeanSerializerBase src) {
            super(src);
        }

        @Override
        public void serialize(Object bean, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {
            UnknownPart up = (UnknownPart) bean;
            jgen.writeStartObject();
            serializeFields(up, jgen, provider);
            jgen.writeEndObject();
        }

        protected void serializeFields(UnknownPart bean, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {
            final BeanPropertyWriter[] props;
            if (_filteredProps != null && provider.getSerializationView() != null) {
                props = _filteredProps;
            } else {
                props = _props;
            }
            int i = 0;
            try {
                for (final int len = props.length; i < len; ++i) {
                    BeanPropertyWriter prop = props[i];
                    if (prop != null) { // can have nulls in filtered list
                        prop.serializeAsField(bean, jgen, provider);
                        bean.tree.remove(prop.getName()); // new
                    }
                }
                if (_anyGetterWriter != null) {
                    _anyGetterWriter.getAndSerialize(bean, jgen, provider);
                }
                // new:
                Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> it = bean.tree.getFields();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    Entry<String, JsonNode> e = it.next();
                    jgen.writeFieldName(e.getKey());
                    jgen.writeObject(e.getValue());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                String name = (i == props.length) ? "[anySetter]"
                        : props[i].getName();
                wrapAndThrow(provider, e, bean, name);
            } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
                /* 04-Sep-2009, tatu: Dealing with this is tricky, since we do not
                 *   have many stack frames to spare... just one or two; can't
                 *   make many calls.
                 */
                JsonMappingException mapE = new JsonMappingException("Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)", e);
                String name = (i == props.length) ? "[anySetter]"
                        : props[i].getName();
                mapE.prependPath(new JsonMappingException.Reference(bean, name));
                throw mapE;
            }
        }
    }
```

In the same time, I wrote a benchmark to confirm (or not) that this solution is faster than JSONObject for big Json strings...
The test compares:
 - read with JSONObject (without mapping)
 - read with Jackson
 - read with tree with Jackson
 - read/write with JSONObject
 - read/write with Jackson
And it is indeed faster :)

After 1000 iterations, excluding potential class load or some initialization the JVM does, i get, in nano seconds:

```
-- AVERAGE ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1|        860,560|        157,772|        234,654|      1,595,018|        488,427|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     |  RO JSONObject|     RO Jackson|    R/- Jackson| R/W JSONObject|    R/W Jackson|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution which I can imagine - is deserializing your JSON into `Map` class (for example LinkedHashMap). Please, see my below example:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String json = "{\"a\":\"java.lang.Integer\",\"b\":\"time json\",\"c\":\"action json\",\"d\":[1,2,3]}";
        System.out.println(json);

        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(json, LinkedHashMap.class);
        map.put("b", "Override property or create new");

        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(map));
    }
}
```

Above program prints:

```
{"a":"java.lang.Integer","b":"time json","c":"action json","d":[1,2,3]}
{"a":"java.lang.Integer","b":"Override property or create new","c":"action json","d":[1,2,3]}
```

If you want to change inner property on the path you can implement it in this way:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String json = "{\"b\":{\"bb\":{\"bbb\":20}}}";
        System.out.println(json);

        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(json, LinkedHashMap.class);
        JsonUpdater updater = new JsonUpdater(map);
        updater.update(Arrays.asList("b", "bb", "bbb"), 4);

        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(map));
    }
}

class JsonUpdater {

    private LinkedHashMap<String, Object> jsonMap;

    public JsonUpdater(LinkedHashMap<String, Object> jsonMap) {
        this.jsonMap = jsonMap;
    }

    public boolean update(Collection<String> propertiesOnThePath, Object newValue) {
        LinkedList<String> path = new LinkedList<String>(propertiesOnThePath);
        String lastProperty = path.removeLast();

        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> objectMap = jsonMap;
        while (!path.isEmpty()) {
            String property = path.poll();
            if (!objectMap.containsKey(property)) {
                return false;
            }

            objectMap = (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>) objectMap.get(property);
        }

        if (!objectMap.containsKey(lastProperty)) {
            return false;
        }

        objectMap.put(lastProperty, newValue);

        return false;
    }
}
```

Above program prints:

```
{"b":{"bb":{"bbb":20}}}
{"b":{"bb":{"bbb":4}}}
```

As we can see: value was changed. But this solution has huge disadvantage - we have to deserialize all JSON. Few thousands bytes String is not a problem for Java, but if you really want to optimaze your program you can play with `ObjectNode` class and `ObjectMapper#readTree` method. Please see below source code:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

public class JacksonProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String json = "{\"a\":\"java.lang.Integer\",\"b\":\"time json\",\"c\":\"action json\",\"d\":[1,2,3]}";
        System.out.println(json);

        ObjectNode jsonTree = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree(json);
        jsonTree.put("b", "Override property or create new");
        System.out.println(jsonTree.toString());
    }
}
```

Above program prints:

```
{"a":"java.lang.Integer","b":"time json","c":"action json","d":[1,2,3]}
{"a":"java.lang.Integer","b":"Override property or create new","c":"action json","d":[1,2,3]}
```

I didn't do any comparison tests, but you can test which solution works faster for you.

Comment: Maybe I did not understand your question. I thought you want to change incoming JSON and return changed version. Let me know how can I improve my answer.

Comment: Your answer gave me a few ideas ... but this is not quite what I need.
Indeed, what my JsonObject example hides is that I want to update an object and not just 1 value. If I reuse your notations, I want to be able to do: jsonTree.put("b", instanceOfObjectB); where ObjectB is a Java object jackson would have auto deserialized its @JsonProperty annotations... (putPojo doesn't help)
After many tries, ... I think I have a solution involving a custom module and bean serializer. I'll post a full example if it works. In the meantime, if you/someone think of an easier approach...