# How to modify JsonNode in Java?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to change a JSON attribute's value in Java, I can get the value properly but I couldn't modify the JSON.

here is the code below

```
  JsonNode blablas = mapper.readTree(parser).get("blablas");
    for (JsonNode jsonNode : blablas) {
        String elementId = jsonNode.get("element").asText();
        String value = jsonNode.get("value").asText();
        if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(elementId, "blabla")) {
            if(value != null && value.equals("YES")){
                 // I need to change the node to NO then save it into the JSON
            }
        }
    }
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You could convert the JsonNode to a Java Map, e.g. `resultMap = mapper.convertValue(aJsonNode, Map.class);` modify it in the Map and then change that Map back to a JsonNode. Just saying.

Answer (score 306, accepted):

`JsonNode` is immutable and is intended for parse operation.  However, it can be cast into `ObjectNode` (and `ArrayNode`) that allow mutations:

```
((ObjectNode)jsonNode).put("value", "NO");
```

For an array, you can use:

```
((ObjectNode)jsonNode).putArray("arrayName").add(object.ge‌​tValue());
```

Comment: tried for a numeric type in which I need to change the value. I got this exception:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.IntNode cannot be cast to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode`

Comment: You need to try "IntNode"

Comment: @balboa_21 changing an integer doesn't really make sense.  It's a bit like me changing 4 to 9, then everyone in the world starts counting 1, 2, 3, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8.  What you want to do is change the field on the object to contain a different integer, so you want to get the object higher up as an ObjectNode, and manipulate the relevant field.

Comment: "ObjectNode.put()" is deprecated, can use "set" instead.

Comment: error: "ObjectNode cannot be resolved to a type"

Answer (score 14):

Adding an answer as some others have upvoted in the comments of the accepted answer they are getting this exception when attempting to cast to ObjectNode (myself included):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TextNode cannot be cast to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode
```

**The solution is to get the 'parent' node, and perform a `put`, effectively replacing the entire node, regardless of original node type.**

If you need to "modify" the node using the existing value of the node:

1. `get` the value/array of the `JsonNode`
2. Perform your modification on that value/array
3. Proceed to call `put` on the parent.

Code, where the goal is to modify `subfield`, which is the child node of `NodeA` and `Node1`:

```
JsonNode nodeParent = someNode.get("NodeA")
                .get("Node1");

// Manually modify value of 'subfield', can only be done using the parent.
((ObjectNode) nodeParent).put('subfield', "my-new-value-here");
```

*Credits:*

I got this inspiration from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28649524/4512948), thanks to [wassgreen@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2138993/wassgren)

Answer (score 7):

I think you can just cast to ObjectNode and use `put` method. Like this

`ObjectNode o = (ObjectNode) jsonNode;
o.put("value", "NO");`

Answer (score 6):

The @Sharon-Ben-Asher answer is ok.

But in my case, for an array i have to use:

```
((ArrayNode) jsonNode).add("value");
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of understanding of others who may not get the whole picture clear following code works for me to find a field and then update it

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(JsonString);    
JsonPointer valueNodePointer = JsonPointer.compile("/GrandObj/Obj/field");
JsonPointer containerPointer = valueNodePointer.head();
JsonNode parentJsonNode = rootNode.at(containerPointer);

if (!parentJsonNode.isMissingNode() && parentJsonNode.isObject()) {
    ObjectNode parentObjectNode = (ObjectNode) parentJsonNode;
    //following will give you just the field name. 
    //e.g. if pointer is /grandObject/Object/field
    //JsonPoint.last() will give you /field 
    //remember to take out the / character 
    String fieldName = valueNodePointer.last().toString();
    fieldName = fieldName.replace(Character.toString(JsonPointer.SEPARATOR), StringUtils.EMPTY);
    JsonNode fieldValueNode = parentObjectNode.get(fieldName);

    if(fieldValueNode != null) {
        parentObjectNode.put(fieldName, "NewValue");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get `ObjectNode` type object in order to set values.
Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11509576/1029621)

Answer (score 0):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> nodeMap = mapper.convertValue(jsonNode, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){});
nodeMap.put("key", "value");
jsonNode = mapper.convertValue(nodeMap, JsonNode.class);
```