# Update JSON values with lambda

Tags: java, json, lambda

I would like to take a JsonNode tree and update each of the values.  Can this be done with a lambda expression?

```
{
    "resource": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3"
    }
}
```

I am trying to use the following logic:

```
JsonNode json = new ObjectMapper().readTree(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(myObject));

ObjectNode rootNode = (ObjectNode) json;
ObjectNode resourceNode = (ObjectNode) rootNode.path("resource");

//Psuedo Code here
resourceNode.forEach(node -> node.value = myFunc(node.value));
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you can, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30997362/how-to-modify-jsonnode-in-java

Comment: @RC it is possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.fields()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#fields()) to iterate over the key/value pairs:

```
resourceNode.fields().forEachRemaining(
    entry -> resourceNode.set(
        entry.getKey(),
        func(entry.getValue())
    )
);
```

Comment: Yep, that's much better

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do that:

```
resourceNode.fieldNames().forEachRemaining(
      s -> resourceNode.set(s, new TextNode(func(resourceNode.get(s).asText())))
);
```