# Repalce a value of a key with jackson properties?

Tags: json, jackson

I am using Jackson and I want to replace a value of my json string but I am not sure how should I do it.
I have a json string like:

```
        "body": {
            "name": "oldname",
            "label": "1234"}
```

I would like to change the value of name to have my json like:

```
        "body": {
            "name": "newname",
            "label": "1234"}
```

so I have:

```
JsonNode parser = objectMapper.readTree(reader);
JsonNode body = parser.path("body");
String newName = "newname";
```

with using

```
body.path("name").asText().replace("oldname","newname");
```

it does not work.

How I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like: ((ObjectNode) body).put("name", newName);

- body.path("name").asText().replace("oldname","newname"),
- here you just replace operation on the string returned by asText() method. It does not modify our input json.

  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  JsonNode parser = objectMapper.readTree(json);
  JsonNode body = parser.path("body");
  String newName = "newname";

  ((ObjectNode) body).put("name", newName);
  //  body.path("name").asText().replace("name", "newname");

  System.out.println(body);

Further Read: [How to modify JsonNode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30997362/how-to-modify-jsonnode-in-java)