# Need to update the value in a Json node

Tags: json, jackson

I have some arbitrary Json and I want to replace some of the text fields with objects.  The text fields have a certain pattern, for example, say they start with a dollar sign $.  I have no idea in advance what the keys are.

The object I want to replace it with is a Pojo probably a Map or List, which can be easily serialized to Json

For example

```
{
   "key1" : "some value",
   "key2" : "$replaceMe",
   "key3" : {
       "key4" : "more complex",
       "key5" : "$andMe"
}
```

So after the replacement, the object would look something like this

```
{
   "key1" : "some value",
   "key2" : {},
   "key3" : {
       "key4" : "more complex",
       "key5" : {}
}
```

where `{}` represents the new object that replaced the string that was previously there

I figured out several ways to traverse the tree, but can't figure out a good way to keep track of the objects to be replaced and how to replace them.

Comment: How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30997362/how-to-modify-jsonnode-in-java?noredirect=1&lq=1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the `JsonNode` nodes of your json file checking the child nodes of every parent node : you can check if there are children nodes representing basic JSON String value with the[`JsonNode#isTextual`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#isTextual()) method and if their text starts with the dollar sign like below:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
//with a generic parent jsnode and one child node of it
if (child.isTextual() && child.asText().startsWith("$")) {
    //delete the old text value and create an empty objectnode
    ((ObjectNode)parent).set(fieldName, mapper.createObjectNode());
}
```

For the creation of an empty `ObjectNode` child you can use the [`ObjectMapper#createObjectNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#createObjectNode()) method like I have done above.

Comment: Thanks, my issues was not realizing I have to go through the parent.  Can I iterate through the parents and change the structure as I go along?

Comment: @PeterKronenberg You are welcome. Yes , you can change it while iterating always storing the parent before and then change the children.

Comment: Moreover, all the nodes you are interested are leaves of the json tree.