# how to update the json with map values using java?

Tags: java, json, mapping

I have below json:

```
{
"type":Flowers,
"input_data": [
    {
      "id": 35742,
      "Request_ID": 8383,
      "data_line": "*****Sample text here*****",      
      "variety": {
        "Rose": 0,
        "Jasmine": 0,
        "Lily": 1,
        "Sunflower": 1,       
      },
      
      "responded": 1
    },
{
      "id": 35992,
      "Request_ID": 8983,
      "data_line": "*****Sample text here*****",      
      "variety": {
        "Rose": 1,
        "Jasmine": 0,
        "Lily": 0,
        "Sunflower": 1,       
      },
      
      "responded": 1
    }
 
  ],
  "token": "F9500930C-15A6-4111-AD7F-7D0DF0CEE4D8"
}
```

How do I map the values in "variety" with "id"?

Note: id is coming from the response of a different API which should be replaced in this json and mapped with variety.

Comment: Take a look at: [Jackson API: partially update a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967531/jackson-api-partially-update-a-string/17981385#17981385), [How to modify the value of a JsonNode recursively using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55560223/how-to-modify-the-value-of-a-jsonnode-recursively-using-jackson/55581639#55581639), [Array of JSON Object to Java POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55248523/array-of-json-object-to-java-pojo/55249189#55249189)

Comment: It sounds like you want to update `id` of each JSON object according to the content of `variety`, respectively?

Comment: @LHCHIN : yes. I need mapping between id and variety.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to have a field like 'input_data' in your json.

Try to redo your json that's aligned to your data model and something that can be mapped to Java objects.

GSON is a great library for dealing with JSONs in Java - https://github.com/google/gson

I can give you a utility method to get a list of Java objects from a json reprenstation like this:

```
private static Type typeOfT = TypeToken.getParameterized(List.class, <<your-class>>.class).getType();

public static <T> List<T> loadListFromFile(String fileName, Class<T> clazz) throws Exception{

File file = new File(fileName);
String json = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
return gson().fromJson(json, typeOfT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your JSON string is invalid (e.g. `Flowers` should be quoted by double quotes). Second, I am confused about what you really want. Therefore, according to the comment under your question, you said that you need a mapping between `id` and `variety`. Here comes one way to achieve that by following steps with `Jackson` (One of the most popular JSON libraries.).

**Step 1**
Create nested POJOs for deserialization.

```java
class Result {
    @JsonProperty("input_data")
    private List<InputData> inputData;

    //general getter and setter
}

class InputData {
    private int id;
    private Variety variety;

    //general getters and setters
}

class Variety {
    @JsonProperty("Rose")
    private int rose;
     
    @JsonProperty("Jasmine")
    private int jasmine;
     
    @JsonProperty("Lily")
    private int lily;
     
    @JsonProperty("Sunflower")
    private int sunflower;

    //general getters, setters and toString()
}
```

**Step 2**
Deserialize JSON response to `Result` and transform the `InputData` into `Map<Integer, Variety>` with Java 8.

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
Result result = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, Result.class);
         
Map<Integer, Variety> idVarietyMap = result.getInputData().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(InputData::getId, InputData::getVariety));
System.out.println(idVarietyMap.toString());
```

**Console output**

```
{35992=Variety [rose=1, jasmine=0, lily=0, sunflower=1], 35742=Variety [rose=0, jasmine=0, lily=1, sunflower=1]}
```